# Install driver Nvidia 304 with software updater ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia

I need to install the nvidia 304 driver.
None of the methods on the Internet worked.
Could install only through software updater.
Reinstalled ubuntu.
Now I see driver but for some reason it is not installed.
Could this be due to permission ?

> [image]

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `nvidia-304` is not available [from official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia-304) of 18.04 LTS.

You can try to add [“Graphics Drivers” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic) to your system first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-304
```

On my system it fails with dependency issue (`xorg-video-abi-23`), so I have e-mailed to PPA owners to get the fix.

Comment: Just an update: the dependency problem remains not solved (2020-08-14).